# Count the matching entries in two different columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to count the items in two columns that match. Here is the example. So in Col1 only A and C are present in Col2. So the output should be 2.

I am looking for a cell formula without adding helper columns. I have tried using `vlookup` but not sure how to use it inside a `Count()` to just count the non #N/A values.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to use a combination of `Count()` and `Match()` functions.

Here is the formula to put in cell D2.

```
=COUNT(MATCH(A:A,B:B,0))
```

Comment: You need to enter this with "CNTRL + SHIFT + ENTER" for this to work as OP intended

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'd solve it. I'd create another column called col1Match. It will have a formula that will output 1 if A was found in col2. Otherwise it would output 0.

Formula:

```
=IF(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2, $B$2:$B$11, 1, FALSE), "") = A2, 1, 0)
```

I'd copy that formula down to the value H in col1. At the bottom I'd do `=SUM(C2:C11)` to get the count.

**Explanation**

`VLOOKUP(A2, $B$2:$B$11, 1, FALSE)` means, look up the value in `A2` in the range B2-B11 and return the value in A2. Say no to a fuzzy match; i.e. just get an exact match. So, VLOOKUP will return NA if no match is found, or it will return the same info that's in A2.

`IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2, $B$2:$B$11, 1, FALSE), "")` means that if VLOOKUP's output was NA, change it to empty string.

Then, that result is compared with the value in A2. If it is the same, output a 1. Otherwise output a 0.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is a `match` function that you can use.

On column D, starting on D2 I had set `=IF(IFERROR(IF(A2<>""; MATCH(A2;B:B;0);"");"")<>"";1;"")`

[image]

And to have the `SUM` just use `=sum(D:D)` maybe on Column E.  And you are good to go!

[Check the link from Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10wPTCPgVK71NMrCMdcxgWunRudcjbcfM1J4VZV9uKEw/edit?usp=sharing)